# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE when creating/updating an Apex class via Tooling API

Tags: apex, tooling-api

I am trying to save an batch apex class dynamically via the tooling api.

```
//I want the batch class to be of the sObject type that user wants.
//Regex replaces %s with className provided by the user.
//Then I post the class via Tooling API.
public class TestBatchExecute {
    public String batchClass='public class TestBatch implements Database.Batchable<%s>{\npublic System.Iterable<%s> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){\nreturn Database.getQueryLocator(\'select id,name from \'+ %s);\n}\npublic void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<%s> scope){for(%s obj:scope){\nsystem.debug(obj);\n}\n}public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){system.debug(\'done job\');}}';
    public TestBatchExecute(String className){
        if(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey(className)){
            try{
                batchClass = batchClass.replaceAll('%s',className);
                System.debug(batchClass);
               
                if(NetworkUtils.generatePostResponse('ApexClass/',JSON.serialize(new PostObject('TestBatch',batchClass)))){
                    system.debug('goodmate');
                }
            }catch(StringException se){
                system.debug(se);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the anonymous window : -

```
new TestBatchExecute('Account');
```

I get the following error : -

````
{"message":"Variable does not exist: Account","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE","fields":[]}```
````

Comment: Any work around for my requirement ?

Comment: Please edit your post and describe your higher-level goals.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: As a side note, have you seen [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155342/2984)? I wrote it a while ago, it may serve your purpose as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happened because your code compiled to:

```
'select id,name from '+ Account
```

Which is invalid.

This code:

```
\'select id,name from \'+ %s
```

Should be:

```
[select name from %s]
```

Note that I recommended you change to an inline query. This will help prevent code that compiles but doesn't run.

---

As a side note, it's rarely necessary to do this; if you use sObject, it can handle any type of object.

```
public class BatchableWhatever implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
  string objectToQuery;
  public BatchableWhatever(sObjectType objectType) {
    objectToQuery = objectType.getDescribe().getName();
  }
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.batchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator('select name from '+objectToQuery);
  }
  public void execute(Database.batchableContext context, sObject[] scope) {
    for(sObject record: scope) {
      System.debug(record.get('Name'));
    }
  }
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    System.debug('Done!');
  }
}
```

---

Also the note of a sObjectType token. This saves you a global describe, because the code can't have typos.