# How is the Start method from Batchable Interface able to return two different return types? Iterable or QueryLocator

Tags: apex, batch

How is the Start method from Batchable Interface able to return two different return types? Iterable or QueryLocator.

As far as Function Overloading is concerned, methods can be overloaded based on different input parameters. But its **not possible** to overload a method based on different Return Types.

What programming feature is used in [Batchable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm#apex_Database_Batchable_start)?
[image]

I tried to create a similar Interface, but its not allowing me to save it.
[image]

Comment: I shared an example "generic batchable" that does this (see [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/155336/2984)); it might handy to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple; the `Database.QueryLocator` implements the `Iterable` interface, so actually you are always returning an Iterable of some form.

You can consider the ability to define your `start` method as returning `Database.QueryLocator` as using the [covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) functionality of other object oriented languages. That the Salesforce documentation specifically shows two different signatures is just to help you understand that both options are available. Covariant return types are not supported across the Apex language, but rather in special cases like this.

It is worth noting that Apex is not a formally defined language and has some weirdnesses.

For example, it doesn't really support generics (templating) either. What you see is somewhat "smoke and mirrors". To illustrate this, you can define a batch class as implementing `Database.Batchable<SObject>` yet the `execute` method (when processing `Account` records, for example) can receive `List<Account>` and there will be no compilation or runtime error (as long as the `start` method selects Account records).

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering. Does that mean Batchable Interface has only one method declaration for Start method? Which should be of signature "System.Iterable start(Database.BatchableContext jobId)", and other signature is only added for our understanding?

Comment: Answer updated to mention covariant return types.