# run a script in the the developer console while implementing interface

Tags: developer-console, queueable-apex, interface

I'm trying to run a script from the developer console with the queueable interface implemented, but the execute method isn't called.

code to put in Execute Anonymous Window in the developer console:

```
public class MyQueueableClass implements Queueable {
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    some code which isn't called....
  }
}

// Enqueue the job
Id jobId = System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueableClass());
System.debug(jobId); // weirdly enough i do get a job id but when I query ApexAsyncJob nothing shows up
```

If this is not possible to implement a queue or a batch in the developer console, it leaves me just with using future, but is there any other way to run async code without creating first a class?

Comment: As @identigral said, the class must be persistent in order for it to actually run successfully. I [use interfaces](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155342/2984) so that I can dynamically alter my batchable's execution in specific ways. I do have to set up the available features before hand, but I don't have to deploy to run an already implemented generator or executor.

Comment: understood, thank you both